# Low-power PWM library: PWM doesnt stop if low_power_pwm_stop is called from handler. Is this a bug?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf51

I am using SDK 12.0.0.

I am working with `low_power_pwm_init()` to initialise the pwm and I have passed a handler while initialising. I want to stop the pwm from the handler hence I am calling `low_power_pwm_stop()` from the handler. I observe that the pwm doesnt stop.

I tried to investigate the reason for this and found that `pwm_timeout_handler()` in low_power_pwm.c is restarting the pwm. Below is the snippet that is suspect.

```
if (p_pwm_instance->pwm_state == NRF_DRV_STATE_INITIALIZED)
{
    p_pwm_instance->pwm_state = NRF_DRV_STATE_POWERED_ON;
    err_code = app_timer_start(*p_pwm_instance->p_timer_id, p_pwm_instance->timeout_ticks, p_pwm_instance);
    APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);
}
```

In `low_power_pwm_stop()`, `p_pwm_instance->pwm_state` is assigned `NRF_DRV_STATE_INITIALIZED` and in the above snippet the timer is started if the driver state is `NRF_DRV_STATE_INITIALIZED`, causing the pwm to be ON again.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had posted this question on nordic's devzone and below is the [answer](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/117047/low-power-pwm-library-pwm-doesnt-stop-if-low_power_pwm_stop-is-called-from-handler-is-this-a-bug/) that I got from a nordic employee.

> Hi,
>
> I can see that this will be the case and will report it internally.
>
> You can set a flag in the event handler and call the stop routine in
> main.
>
> Ole

So I guess this is a bug in nordic's sdk code.